# How render elements based on device in server side using sightly (HTL)

Tags: aem, sightly

Try to render elements based on device screen size, say for example I have two DIVs (desktop and mobile) and I wanted to render desktop DIV for desktop user only and mobile so on.

```
<sly data-sly-test="${ANY_LOGIC_HERE}">
    <div class="desktop-render">
        <button type="button" aria-label="${item.Label}" class="btn btn-primary btn-desktop">Click Here</button>
    </div>
</sly>
<sly data-sly-test="${ANY_LOGIC_HERE}">
    <div class="mobile-render">
        <button type="button" aria-label="${item.Label}" class="btn btn-primary btn-mobile">Click Here</button>
    </div>
</sly>
```

I know there was some CSS/JS trick, but I need it through server sides. So that on-page view source can have only one div.

Comment: So you sacrifice cacheability for having a few lines less in html (or for not needing to do it in the FE)?  Not the best option I would guess, especially not with AEM.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering this, I'll remind you that it's generally bad practice to render different markup per device/user-agent. That makes your pages non-cacheable and user-agent is generally not very reliable. There are other techniques, from client-side DOM manipulation to dedicated mobile pages (which you could redirect to in case the device is a mobile).

That said, there's a helper [MobileUtil](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/mobile/core/MobileUtil.html#isMobileRequest-org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest-) that you could leverage in your Use-Object/Sling Model to determine if the device requesting the page seems to be a mobile.

Make sure to check all [AEM server-side mobile APIs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/mobileweb/mobile.html?lang=en#server-side-mobile-api)!